# Permissions for Linked Server Remote Login

Tags: sql, linked-server

I am trying to connect 2 databases (not on same server or domain) using Linked Servers.  Below is the query I am running to connect the 2.

My problem is that if I specify @rmtuser = 'sa', I am able to connect just fine.  However, if I switch @rmtuser to 'RemoteIntegrationUser', I get an error saying unable to connect. (Error 18456)

I have verified that I can connect directly to the "Remote" server via SSMS using the 'RemoteIntegrationUser' account and it connects just fine.

Is there some special permission 'RemoteIntegrationUser' must have on the "Remote" server in order to be able to handle these incoming connections?

```
Exec sp_dropserver 'RemoteDB', 'droplogins'
go


EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'RemoteDB'
   ,@srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for SQL'
   ,@provider = N'SQLNCLI'
   ,@datasrc = '111.2222.33.44'
   ,@catalog = 'myremotedb'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname = N'RemoteDB'
   ,@useself = false
   ,@locallogin = 'LocalIntegrationUser'
   ,@rmtuser = N'RemoteIntegrationUser'
   ,@rmtpassword = N'************'
go
```

Comment: I've read that it shouldn't matter, but my local server is SQL2008 R2 and my remote server is SQL2005.

Comment: good article on this problem. Troubleshooting Error 18456 https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456 from Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FACE SMACK**

Talk about missing the forest for the trees.  Somehow I wound up using the wrong password.  Swore I was using the correct one, but nope.  Once again, the weakest link in the human/computer relationship turns out to be NOT the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are linking 2 SQL Servers, try defining the @srvproduct as `N'SQL Server'`. I am not sure if the instances being on separate domains will allow that. You may also want to try setting `@locallogin = NULL` when defining the linked server login:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
     @server = N'<server name/ip>'
    ,@srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
     @rmtsrvname = N'<server name or ip>'
    ,@locallogin = NULL
    ,@useself = N'False'
    ,@rmtuser = N'RemoteIntegrationUser'
    ,@rmtpassword = N'************'
GO
```

Other than that, does the RemoteIntegrationUser have connect permissions to the myremotedb database?

Comment: Yeah, I am able to connect (via SSMS) to myremotedb using the RemoteIntegrationUser.  Just not via Linked Servers.  I'll try your suggestions and report back

Comment: I tried each of your suggestions individually and combined and I'm still getting the same error.